# Clustering with mix variables in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to build a clustering model following the kmeans method using both continous and categoric variables.

The goal is to create clusters based on the gender, age, occupation, billing plan, cell phone and the usage on some applications

I'm struggeling on how to process the categorical data, I know i should turn them onto dummies but not quite sure on how to do it in all the categoric variables all at once.

Thank you

The table looks like:

ID  Gender  Age Occupation  Plan    Cell phone  Amazon Prime GB DL  Apple Music GB DL   Audible DB DL
C001    NR  56  Student Archaius    SAMSUNG 0   0   0.498829165
C002    M   25  Management  Malawi  HUAWEI  0   0   1
C003    H   32  Professor   Archaius    Apple   0   0   0.632005841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution to create dummy variables from categorical variables is the "fastDummies" Package:

```
library(fastDummies)
df <- data.frame(NR1 = c(1,2,3),
                 NR2 = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.7),
                 FA1 = factor(c("A","B","C")),
                 FA2 = factor(c("5","6","7")))

str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ NR1: num  1 2 3
 $ NR2: num  0.1 0.5 0.7
 $ FA1: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ FA2: Factor w/ 3 levels "5","6","7": 1 2 3

# one variable per factor level
fastDummies::dummy_cols(df)
  NR1 NR2 FA1 FA2 FA1_A FA1_B FA1_C FA2_5 FA2_6 FA2_7
1   1 0.1   A   5     1     0     0     1     0     0
2   2 0.5   B   6     0     1     0     0     1     0
3   3 0.7   C   7     0     0     1     0     0     1

# encoding where where there are n-1 columns per factor (as in case of all being 0 it implies the last is 1 already)
fastDummies::dummy_cols(df, remove_first_dummy = TRUE)
  NR1 NR2 FA1 FA2 FA1_B FA1_C FA2_6 FA2_7
1   1 0.1   A   5     0     0     0     0
2   2 0.5   B   6     1     0     1     0
3   3 0.7   C   7     0     1     0     1
```